# Launching vino-server on display :0 at boot

Tags: raspbian, boot, xorg, vnc

I run my Raspberry Pi with `Raspbian` with an `X` server running but without a monitor connected to it. I installed `tightvncserver` and now running:

```
vncserver :1 -geometry 1600x900 -depth 24
```

I can have a `lightdm` desktop session to connect to.

However, in this way, a totally new `lightdm` desktop session is created. This session is different from the one I see on my TV and that eats up another 20 megs of RAM. Obviously, this is not the best solution that can be achieved.

So I installed `vino`: I've already used it in Ubuntu with almost no problems at all. However, on `Raspbian`, I'm facing a weird problem when trying to have it launched after the first `lightdm` login. Given that `Desktop Session Settings` doesn't allow to add new entries via its graphical interface, I created a `vino-server.desktop` launcher (that calls `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server`) and I moved it to `/etc/xdg/autostart/`. This method also used to work in `Knoppix`, so I was somewhat confident. In fact, within `Desktop Session Settings` the new launcher was present and enabled.

After a reboot, no `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server` process was running. However, I know that the procedure is almost correct, because if I launch another `vncserver` session, I can see a `vino-server` process popping up inside the process list.

So the question is: what am I doing wrong? Why does this method work for any other `lightdm` session except the main one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I've made it! The procedure was almost correct. I was just missing a few little details.

First, the timings: putting `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server` directly in `lightdm` autostart launched it before the `X` session was completely set-up. So I wrapped it into a script with a little bit of delay before the command:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 5
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server &
```

In turn, this script was called by a `vino-server.desktop` launcher, placed into `/etc/xdg/autostart/` directory.

Second, permissions: the `lightdm` config file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` was enabling autologin for user `pi`:

```
#> grep ^autologin /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

autologin-user=pi
```

But I already created my own user and the wrapper script was in my home folder, so some weird permission issue was preventing its execution. I changed the `autologin-user` setting in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` to my user, and now everything works fine. Finally I can access my `:0` display through `VNC` right after boot.